# Excel VBA- Nested For...Next loop to compare two values- Not looping through all values in range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on putting together a macro that automates the manual selection of a symbol (up/down arrow, equal sign) based on whether or not a value has moved up/down a quartile or stayed the same quarter over quarter.

I'm using three FOR EACH.... NEXT loops, each with it's own set of embedded if,elseif, else statements. I'm thinking the proper way to handle this is to have the first loop run through the first old value (A1 for example), and bucket it in the proper UDF bucket where it is assigned its quartile number. Once that loop ends, have the new loop run with the same procedures. Once both values have been assigned, the third loop will compare the two quartile numbers and then make the symbol input. It will then start over and loop through all of the cells in the specified range until all are set.

The loop looks to be iterating correctly, but it doesn't seem to hit all values in the range.

I think my issue is with the way the loops are set up. Does anyone know a better way to handle this?

Ideally, the code looks at the first value in column b and assigns the 'currentQuart' variable a value, followed by looping into column a and assigning the 'oldQuart' variable a value. Once that is done, the third loop compares the two values and inputs a character based on the operator.

**Functions, stored in module:**

Function quartOne(ByVal cellValue As Variant) As Boolean
        quartOne = (cellValue >= 0.01 And cellValue <= 25)
    End Function

```
Function quartTwo(ByVal cellValue As Variant) As Boolean
    quartTwo = (cellValue >= 25.01 And cellValue <= 50)
End Function

Function quartThree(ByVal cellValue As Variant) As Boolean
    quartThree = (cellValue >= 50.01 And cellValue <= 75)
End Function

Function quartFour(ByVal cellValue As Variant) As Boolean
    quartFour = (cellValue > 75)
End Function
```

**Code**

Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim cellOld As Range, cellCurrent As Range, cell As Range
Dim oldRng1
Dim currentRng1 As Range

Dim oldQuart As Integer
Dim currentQuart As Integer


Set oldRng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4")

Set currentRng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B4")


    For Each cellCurrent In currentRng1.Cells

            For Each cellOld In oldRng1.Cells

                    For Each cell In currentRng1.Cells

                    'checks cellCurrent against functions in module and assigns variable
                        If quartOne(cellCurrent.Value) Then
                            currentQuart = 1
                        ElseIf quartTwo(cellCurrent.Value) Then
                            currentQuart = 2
                        ElseIf quartThree(cellCurrent.Value) Then
                            currentQuart = 3
                        ElseIf quartFour(cellCurrent.Value) Then
                            currentQuart = 4
                        Else
                        End If


                    'checks cellOld against functions in module and assigns variable
                                 If quartOne(cellOld.Value) Then
                                        oldQuart = 1
                                ElseIf quartTwo(cellOld.Value) Then
                                        oldQuart = 2
                                ElseIf quartThree(cellOld.Value) Then
                                        oldQuart = 3
                                ElseIf quartFour(cellOld.Value) Then
                                        oldQuart = 4
                                Else
                                End If


                        'takes variable from above loops, runs through if/else and inputs corresponding character
                            If currentQuart = 1 And oldQuart = 1 Then
                                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H3D)
                            ElseIf currentQuart = 1 And oldQuart > 1 Then
                                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H2191)
                            ElseIf currentQuart = 2 And oldQuart < 2 Then
                                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H2193)
                            ElseIf currentQuart = 2 And oldQuart = 2 Then
                                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H3D)
                            ElseIf currentQuart = 2 And oldQuart > 2 Then
                                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H2191)
                            ElseIf currentQuart = 3 And oldQuart > 3 Then
                                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H2191)
                            ElseIf currentQuart = 3 And oldQuart = 3 Then
                                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H3D)
                            ElseIf currentQuart = 3 And oldQuart < 3 Then
                                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H2193)
                            ElseIf currentQuart = 4 And oldQuart < 4 Then
                                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H2191)
                            ElseIf currentQuart = 2 And oldQuart = 4 Then
                                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H3D)
                            End If
                            Exit For

                Next cell
             Next cellOld
     Next cellCurrent


End Sub
```

**!Test Data is stored as single values (1-100) in column a-b!**

Comment: What specifically is your problem/error?  I see no question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Added the question.

Comment: Try stepping through the code with `F8` and follow how VBA does your loops. It's pretty useful to spot when a loop isn't working properly, as you can see the code run line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running too many loops.

simply loop once with a standard for loop and compare each cell row by row.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim oldRng1 As Range
Dim currentRng1 As Range

Dim oldQuart As Integer
Dim currentQuart As Integer


Set oldRng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4")
Set currentRng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B4")


For i = 1 To currentRng1.Rows.Count

    'checks cellCurrent against functions in module and assigns variable
    If quartOne(currentRng1(i, 1).Value) Then
        currentQuart = 1
    ElseIf quartTwo(ccurrentRng1(i, 1).Value) Then
        currentQuart = 2
    ElseIf quartThree(currentRng1(i, 1).Value) Then
        currentQuart = 3
    ElseIf quartFour(currentRng1(i, 1).Value) Then
        currentQuart = 4
    Else
    End If

    'checks cellOld against functions in module and assigns variable
    If quartOne(oldRng1(i, 1).Value) Then
        oldQuart = 1
    ElseIf quartTwo(oldRng1(i, 1).Value) Then
        oldQuart = 2
    ElseIf quartThree(oldRng1(i, 1).Value) Then
        oldQuart = 3
    ElseIf quartFour(oldRng1(i, 1).Value) Then
        oldQuart = 4
    Else
    End If

    'takes variable from above loops, runs through if/else and inputs corresponding character
    If currentQuart = 1 And oldQuart = 1 Then
        currentRng1(i, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H3D)
    ElseIf currentQuart = 1 And oldQuart > 1 Then
        currentRng1(i, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H2191)
    ElseIf currentQuart = 2 And oldQuart < 2 Then
        currentRng1(i, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H2193)
    ElseIf currentQuart = 2 And oldQuart = 2 Then
        currentRng1(i, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H3D)
    ElseIf currentQuart = 2 And oldQuart > 2 Then
        currentRng1(i, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H2191)
    ElseIf currentQuart = 3 And oldQuart > 3 Then
        currentRng1(i, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H2191)
    ElseIf currentQuart = 3 And oldQuart = 3 Then
        currentRng1(i, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H3D)
    ElseIf currentQuart = 3 And oldQuart < 3 Then
        currentRng1(i, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H2193)
    ElseIf currentQuart = 4 And oldQuart < 4 Then
        currentRng1(i, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H2191)
    ElseIf currentQuart = 2 And oldQuart = 4 Then
        currentRng1(i, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = ChrW(&H3D)
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you, Scott!

Comment: @Escott please help us keep the site clean by marking this as correct.  One does this by clicking on the check mark by the answer.